# Zepto's $.post does not have error handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, zepto

I'm using `Zepto` in my application as an alternate to `jQuery` and I was working on a task when I realized, `$.ajax` have a error handler, but other methods like `$.post`, `$.get` does not have it.

What can be the reason for this?

#### Function Signature

> $.post(url, [data], function(data, status, xhr){ ... }, [dataType])
>
> $.get(url, [data], [function(data, status, xhr){ ... }], [dataType])

#### References

1. [$.ajax](http://zeptojs.com/#$.ajax)
2. [$.post](http://zeptojs.com/#$.post)
3. [$.get](http://zeptojs.com/#$.get)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your question about `$.get` and `$.post`. Yes, [source code on github](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L312) answered that there is no error handlers for this methods, but you can add common error handler in `$.ajaxSettings`

**But** instead of `$.ajax` with callbacks better use Zepto [deferred API](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/deferred.js#files). You must include [it manually](http://zeptojs.com/#modules).

It provides `$.Deferred` promises API. Depends on the "callbacks" module. 
When included, `$.ajax()` supports a promise interface for chaining callbacks.

With deferred you can catch error in deferred/promise chains:

```
$.post(/*any options*/).done(/*success handler*/).fail(/*error handler*/)
```

or

```
$.post().then(function() {
   // success code here
}, function() {
   // error code here
});
```

Comment: Its a good answer, but as I said in question `$.ajax` has error handler and I have updated my code to use it. Question is why is error handler missing in remaining methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, it's just how the jQuery API which Zepto emulates is designed (see eg https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

If you need the callbacks use $.ajax, the global callbacks or promises.

Comment: One point is missed - jQuery return jqXHR (it have error method), Zepto native xhr. So error handler is really missed in Zepto design.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the error handler is not available because it would add confusion.
The current function specification:

`$.get(url, [data], [function(data, status, xhr){ ... }], [dataType])`

when adding an error handler param will be transformed to:

`$.get(url, [data], [function(data, status, xhr){ ... }], [function(data, status, xhr){ ... }], [dataType])`

In the case of an additional error handler parameter, it would be hard to understand what handler you mean when making an ajax call:

```
$.get('http://example.com', {query: 1}, function(result) {
    //Handle the request
});
```

In this case the handler is for error or success? It's quite hard to understand. Of course you could add some additional `null`s it the params, but it's not a clean solution and adds confusion.

The $.ajax has an error handler because it accepts the options as a JavaScript object. It doesn't make any issues if you specify or not the error handler function as a property of the options object.

**The solution:**
Just use the promises approach:

```
var xhr = $.post(...);
xhr.done(function(data, status, xhr){ 
  //Handle when success
}).fail(function(xhr, errorType, error){
  //Handle when an error occurred.
}).always(function(){ 
  //A handler executed always, on success or error
  //Use this to hide the loading image for example
})
```

When invoked, the ajax call function will return a promise object. Attach to the promise your success (using `done()` method) and error (`using fail()` method) handlers.
The `always()` is executed in any case (after the execution of `done()`  or `fail()` handlers). It is useful to finish any work related with the request, for example to hide a loading image.

Answer (score 0):

An extension to @Pinal's answer, I believe `parseArguments` function is creating issue:

#### Original Code

**GET**

```
$.get = function(/* url, data, success, dataType */){
  return $.ajax(parseArguments.apply(null, arguments))
}
```

**Parse Arguments**

```
function parseArguments(url, data, success, dataType) {
  if ($.isFunction(data)) dataType = success, success = data, data = undefined
  if (!$.isFunction(success)) dataType = success, success = undefined
  return {
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
  }
}
```

#### Possible Solution

```
function parseArguments(url, data, success, error, dataType) {
  if ($.isFunction(data)) dataType = success, success = data, data = undefined
  if (!$.isFunction(success)) dataType = success, success = undefined
  if (!$.isFunction(error)) dataType = error, error = undefined
  return {
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    error:error,
    dataType: dataType
  }
}
```

But yes, this might be a generic function and changing it might have big impact.